# How to extract values from MongoDB into JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have simple Mongodb collection called `db_userProfile`. In the collection schema there is:

```
native_language: {
    type: String,
}
```

How can I extract that string value, and put it in a JavaScript variable?

Comment: Something like db_userProfile.native_language should be sufficient. If it won't work, please post object with data

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned JavaScript, so I guess you use Node.js
Here is an example how it can be achived with mongodb driver for node.js

```
// Retrieve
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// Connect to the db
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/exampleDb", function(err, db) {
  if(err) { return console.dir(err); }

  var collection = db.collection('db_userProfile');
  collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
    //items is JavaScript variable that contains data from mongodb collection

  });
});
```

more infor is [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-articles/nodekoarticle1.html)

Also you can use [mongoosejs](http://mongoosejs.com/)